# What's the purpose of having class names between "Less than" and "Greater than" symbols in C#?

Tags: c#, class, generics, declaration

I don't understand the following class declaration:

```
public abstract class Class1 <TDomainServiceContract, TDomainService>
{
   ...
}
```

I know what `TDomainServiceContract`  and  `TDomainService` are, but why are they used between the `<` and `>` symbols?

Comment: They are [generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx).

Comment: thanks, but why did you ask to close this question, like some other users, saying that it is not a real question? I see that in my "message" there is a question mark, maybe it is not rendered in your browser? I need to understand how this site works...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The parameters between the `<` and `>` are generic type parameters. Generics, at a very high level, allow you to design a class that is agnostic about the *particular* type of one or more of its parameters, properties, or methods. It's a little difficult to explain with words, but the most common use of generics is in collections.

Before generics, most developers used things like `ArrayList` to keep track of collections of objects. The downside to this was safety; because you could put any `object` in an `ArrayList`, that meant that you had to cast your object back to the expected type (making code less clean), and you had nothing stopping you from adding something that *wasn't* that type of object (i.e. I could have an `ArrayList` that I might be expecting to contain only `string` objects, but I might--accidentally--put in an `int` or a `DbConnection`, etc.), and you'd never find out until runtime when your cast failed.

```
ArrayList myStrings = new ArrayList();

myStrings.Add("foo");
myStrings.Add("bar");
myStrings.Add(1); // uh-oh, this isn't going to turn out well...

string string1 = (string)myStrings[0];
string string2 = (string)myStrings[1];
string string3 = (string)myStrings[2]; // this will compile fine but fail at 
                                       // runtime since myStrings[2] is an int, 
                                       // not a string
```

After generics were introduced, we got the `List<T>` class. This is a single class that takes a single generic type argument--namely, the type of objects that you're expecting the list to contain. That way, I can have a `List<string>` or a `List<int>` that will a) not require casting, since the indexers return `string` and `int`, respectively, and b) be safe at compile time, as I know that nothing other than a `string` or an `int` (again, respectively) can be put into those lists.

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();

myStrings.Add("foo");
myStrings.Add("bar");
myStrings.Add(1); // this will not compile, as an int is not a string
```

The point of generics is to say that you don't care about what the *actual* type is of the object that you're working with, but the consumer of your class might. In other words, the mechanics of how a list might store a `string`, an `int`, a `DbConnection`, etc. are idential, but generics make it so that this type information coming from the consumer of your class isn't lost in your abstraction.

Comment: +1 I'm just starting to learn C# and this was exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

These are [generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx).

They mean the class is a generic class, in your example with constraints on the types - both need to be `DomainContext` or classes that derive from it.

See [Introduction to Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's indicating that when using the class you can provide any type for the `TDomainServiceContract` that implements `DomainContext`. So let's assume a class like this:

```
public class MyDomainContext : DomainContext
{
    ...
}
```

I can use that class when creating a new `Class1` like this:

```
var o = new Class1<MyDomainContext, MyDomainService>();
```

because it implements `DomainContext`.  The same goes for the `TDomainService`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is in a simpler example.  For instance:

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String>();
myStrings.Add("One");
//Etc.
```

In this example, you are simply identifying which data type you will be using with the class.  Similar situation in your example.